# Decoding string xml in .net

Tags: c#

Hy,

i want to decode a string which contain xml data in .net
but that string was encoded in java

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();
byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
result = new String(decoded_char);
return result;
```

i have written that code but it throw error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For the love of all that is binary please provide the error.

Comment: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

Comment: @jats: Then that sounds like it's not base64 to start with - what made you think it was?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it really is UTF-8 which is then base64-encoded, you should just be able to write:

```
byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binary);
```

However, it sounds like it *wasn't* base64-encoded to start with - if you've already got it as text, you should be able to use it without any extra work.